# how to set up nulldb in rails with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm almost new to rails development. I'm currently reading Avdi Grimm's Objects on Rails for having a #SOLID design in my rails apps instead of being forced to some conventions which will create mess and unreadable code and design.

I wanna setup nulldb and use it in my fast specs which are testing the business logic of the application but I can't get it to work. I read the installation guide at nulldb GitHub page here -> https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb. I installed the activerecord-nulldb-adapter gem and put it also in my Gemfile and ran the bundle install command so it's completely installed now. I have a spec_helper_lite.rb file which I use in my fast specs so I though it's a good idea to setup nulldb in it. Here's the code for nulldb part in my spec_helper_lite.rb file:

```
require 'nulldb_rspec'

def setup_nulldb
    schema_path = File.expand_path("../db/schema.rb", File.dirname(__FILE__))
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => :nulldb,
                                                        :schema => schema_path)
    NullDB.nullify(:schema => schema_path)
end

def teardown_nulldb
    NullDB.restore
end
```

then I require this spec_helper_lite.rb in my fast specs and I call the setup and teardown nulldb method in before and after methods of my spec. when I run the specs I'll get the error Uninitialized Constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (NameError). I tried different things like removing that establish_connection line in the setup_nulldb and I'll get the same error. I even required 'active_record' in my spec_helper_lite just to see what will happen and then I'll get the error "undefined method nullify" for NullDB module and obviously the spec became completely slow cause of requiring active_record. I searched a lot about how to setup nulldb and everything I saw explained about setting it up this way but it doesn't work for me. I use nulldb version 0.2.1, rails 3.0.0 and rspec 2.0.1

I appreciate your help about how to set this up correctly. Thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: hi! Would you mind posting this as an issue to the NullDB github project? The maintenance team can probably help you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues (but using minitest, and activerecord independent of rails). I tried all the same stuff you mentioned. Turns out I was just using whatever was in rubygems. It looks like updating my Gemfile to pull directly from github resolved the issue:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter', :git => 'git://github.com/nulldb/nulldb.git'
end
```

You'll want to `bundle install` again after updating.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for *nulldb*?